# .reg files Current Directory

Tags: directory-listing

Is there a way that I could use the Current Directory instead of a specified file with this?

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\LostSagaLA]
"Path"="D:\Fantasy LS"
"URL Protocol"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\LostSagaLA\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\LostSagaLA\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\LostSagaLA\shell\open\command]
@="D:\\Fantasy LS\\lswebbroker.exe %1"
```

Comment: Did you try with `REG ADD` command in `cmd`?

Answer (score 1):

Which "current directory"? Every instance of every running program could have it's own.
You could run a batch file which sets the desired "current directory", and then
writes to the .reg file using `echo <text containing %CD% psuedo-variable at appropriate location> >> yourregfile.reg`. Batch file would then call regedit.exe to process the .reg file.